# Pass an array as value in an ado.net DBParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, ado.net

The project I'm working on has a lot of IN-queries like:

```
SELECT something, anotherthing
FROM atable
WHERE something IN (value1, value2, value3)
```

This is an example of a query with 3 parameters in the IN-part but the same query could be executed with 1 or 2 or 5 or 10 or ... parameters.
The problem is that each query has an other execution plan in the database with makes it slow.

I'd like to hava a query like this:

```
SELECT something, anotherthing
FROM atable
WHERE something IN (@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

or this:

```
SELECT something, anotherthing
FROM atable
WHERE something IN (@values)
```

I have accomplished the first query with some helper function, but I still have different execution plan per number of parameters. This could be solved with the second one.

What is the best way to pass an array as database parameter? I'm using Oracle and SQL Server, solutions for both of them are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL-Server, there are two common approaches for this. The third option **to be avoided** is to pass in a `varchar` and concatenate it into a dynamic SQL statement with `IN` - this is a clear injection attack surface.

Reasonable options:

- pass in a `varchar` and use a UDF to split the data on a delimiter ([like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685542/user-defined-function-replacing-where-col-in)), perhaps comma, pipe, tab, etc. Join to the result:

  ```
  SELECT something, anotherthing
  FROM atable a
  INNER JOIN dbo.SplitUDF(@values) udf
          ON udf.Value = a.something
  ```
- use a [table-valued-parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) (SQL2008) and join directly (avoid the UDF)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to support SQL Server 2000 and 2005, no table-valued-paramter for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these articles

- [MSSQL Limitations and Arrays](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article79.aspx)
- [Passing Arrays in SQL Parameters
  using XML Data Type in SQL Server
  2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/PassingArraysSQLParameter.aspx)
- [Since there is no Sqlserver array
  parameter, what’s the best way to
  proceed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014571/since-there-is-no-sqlserver-array-parameter-whats-the-best-way-to-proceed)
- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server
  2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

This is an example of using the [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx) type to create a list

```
--Split
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT  @data = 'A,B,C',
        @delimiter = ','

SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code does the trick. You can create your own BuildQuery(???) function.

```
    public void RemoveDependencies(int versionID, int[] deps)
    {
        if (versionID <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (deps == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (deps.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string query = "DELETE FROM Dependencies WHERE version_id = @VersionId AND dep_version_id IN (";
        int n = deps.Length;
        string key;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (deps[i] <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            key = String.Format("@dep{0}", i);
            query += key;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, deps[i]);
            if (i < n - 1)
            {
                 query += ", ";
            }
        }
        query += ")";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VersionId", versionID);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        using (SqlConnection con = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No rows affected! Illegal id.");
            }
        }
    }
```