# String conversion for SQL select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

Using a SELECT statement I query a database and get back a result in the format: name1,name2,name3

Depending on the database entry this result could have any number of names: name1,name2...name(n)

I would like to use this data to query another database like so:

```
SELECT Name, SerialNo, Model FROM InstrumentTable where ID=1 and InstName IN name1,name2,name3
```

In order to do this I need to convert name1,name2,name3 to ('name1','name2','name3')

I have tried splitting the String into an array of Strings

```
    Dim ref1s As String = cmdf1.ExecuteScalar()
    Dim fields() As String = Nothing
    fields = ref1s.Split(",")
```

and then concatenating them in an array

```
For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Count - 1
     MsgBox(String.Concat("'", fields(i), "'"))
 Next
```

but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet.

Adding the brackets at the start and end of the string shouldn't be a problem just adding the quotes to each name and separating them with a comma is the issue.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968763/pass-an-array-as-value-in-an-ado-net-dbparameter

Comment: If you are using sql server 2008 or above, toucans use table values parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a  bit previous

```
For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Count - 1
  fields[i] = String.Concat("'",fields[i],"'")
Next
```

Then

```
strValue = fields.Join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

user557425,

Something like this might point you in the right direction:

```
Dim lst As List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 0 to fields.Count - 1
    if i = fields.Count - 1 Then
       lst.Add(fields(i) & "'")
    Else
        lst.Add(fields(i) & "','")
    End if
Next

Dim sqlSB As StringBuilder
sqlSB.Append("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE BLAH IN(")
For each s As String in lst
     sqlSB.Append(s)
Next

'use the stringbuilder as command text in a SqlCommand...
```